# Can I control which artifacts are available in Sonatype Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm using [Sonatypes Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) on our local network to centralize our maven artifact downloads. I can already see that we're using a **lot of different versions of certain libraries** and I want to **control which versions of those versions are available** to the local users.

I started to read about *Nexus Professional* and the staging repositories and it sounds like a solution for this. However, can I **control the available artifacts in standard nexus** too?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Check out the [procurement suite functionality](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/procure.html) that comes with nexus professional.

There's a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-ZRfD7OroM) available

In a nutshell it allows you to create a hosted repository whose content is controlled by a set of rules, which you control via the management screen.

Comment: Correct. Both the staging and procurement functionality are part of Nexus Professional

Comment: For a free solution you could checkout artifactory http://www.jfrog.com/features.php. I have never used it, however it has security features enabling you to control access at the artifact level

Comment: I'll have a look at it and compare it to Nexus. I chose Nexus because the UI is easy to use, but if Artifactory gives me this fine-grained control in a open source/free version I'll consider switching. Thanks.